# LINQ to xml query accessing unknown titled element

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I've got an xml document of the following structure which I'm trying to query in C# with LINQ to xml

```
<recurrence>
    <rule>
        <firstDayOfWeek>mo</firstDayOfWeek>
        <repeat>
            <weekly mo="TRUE" fr="TRUE" weekFrequency="1" />
        </repeat>
    <repeatForever>FALSE</repeatForever>
    </rule>
</recurrence>
```

I'm trying to query it to determine information about what's contained in the xml and building an object based on that.

Within the "repeat" element the title of the element within can be weekly (as in the sample) daily, monthly or yearly.

I'm having trouble selecting the weekly element. As I'm not sure it's going to be called weekly I'm trying to below

```
XDocument info = XDocument.Parse(source.RecurrenceData);

var data = from d in info.Descendants("recurrence").Descendants("rule").Descendants("repeat") 
           select d;

var element = data.Elements().First();
```

This is always coming out as null. What would be the easiest way for me to select this element, whether it be a daily, weekly, monthly or yearly element and then determine the various attributes that may or may not be contained within in it?

Comment: Code seem correct. What is source.RecurrenceData?

Comment: This *looks* like a namespacing problem. Does your markup contain namespace definitions (`xmlns` attributes)?

Comment: source.RecurrenceData is a string, which I'm sure contains the above as it's come from a copy paste of that variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have placed the following code in a console application and the element is not null. Are you sure that your `source.RecurrenceData` is correct?

```
string xml = @"<recurrence>
                <rule>
                    <firstDayOfWeek>mo</firstDayOfWeek>
                    <repeat>
                        <weekly mo=""TRUE"" fr=""TRUE"" weekFrequency=""1"" />
                    </repeat>
                <repeatForever>FALSE</repeatForever>
                </rule>
            </recurrence>";

XDocument info = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var data = from d in info.Descendants("recurrence").Descendants("rule").Descendants("repeat") select d;

var element = data.Elements().First();
```

Comment: I'm sure that my source.RecurrenceData is correct, also when I step through in debug I can see that my data variable contains the "Repeat" element. Element however always remains as null

Comment: Ok.. that's strange.. When I debug it everything is working. Does the above example work for you? Can you spot any differences with your code?

Comment: I've actually just tried this in a console app and I've found the same thing... For some reason it's getting the element. In my other solution however it simply remains null. Thanks for the console app idea